# how to separate total hours from database field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fill in this hour and minute column whose data is taken from the data field overtime_total_hour.

[image]

This is the code I'm using, I don't know how to fill in the values so that the hours and minutes can be called from the overtime table which is from the overtime_total_hour field.

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <label class="d-block">Lama Lembur</label>
            <input id="hours" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" maxlength="2" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 25%; display: inline-block" name="overtime_total_hour" value="">
           <span style="margin-left: 10px">Jam</span>
            <input id="minutes" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" maxlength="2" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 25%; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px" name="overtime_total_minutes" value="">
            <span style="margin-left: 10px">Menit</span>
 </div>
```

Field from table overtime

[image]

```
{{dd($overtime->overtime_total_hour)}}
```

[image]

I want to change like this.

[image]

Comment: Well using PHP you would need to split the string at the `.`, could use `explode()` for an example, see the docs about passing data to views: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views but if you must do that in your blade file with PHP, you can with Raw Php: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#raw-php

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$lembur = explode(".",$overtime->overtime_total_hour);
echo $lembur[0]; //Jam "2"
echo $lembur[1]; //Menit "22"
```